# action of étale fundamental group on the cover

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I have a Galois cover $f \colon Y \rightarrow X$, i.e $f$ is finite étale and $deg(f) = Aut_X(Y)$. The étale fundamental group $\pi_1(X,\bar{x})$ acts on the geometric fiber $Y_{\bar{x}}$, but is that also true that there is an action of the étale fundamental group $\pi_1(X,\bar{x})$ on $Y$? If yes how can I define such an action?

Comment: The étale fundamental group comes *by definition* with a canonical projection $\pi_1^{ét}(X,\bar x)\to \mathrm{Aut}(Y/X)$. In fact it is defined as the limit of those automorphism groups as $Y$ runs through the Galois covers...

Comment: I thought the fundamental group is the automorphism group $Aut(F_{\bar{x}})$ where $F_{\bar{x}}$ is the functor from finite etale morphisms over $X$ to sets by taking the geometric fiber of $\bar{X}$. Are these definitions equivalent?

Comment: @AnhDungLe Yes they are equivalent. I recommend studying Grothendieck Galois theory before asking questions about the topic on MO.

Comment: You should be heavily analogizing with algebraic topology at every step. The definitions given by Denis Nardin are equivalent because the fiber, seen as a $\pi_1$-set, has the same automorphism group as the cover does — namely, the deck group.

Comment: @Denis Nardin I am studying with [Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BQ8) and Tamas Szamuely's Galois groups and fundamental groups and both of them only have the definition with fiber functor.

Comment: @Santana Afton I find it difficult to analogize, since in topology I can think with actual loops and universal cover but I cannot do it here in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the definition I gave is the one in construction 3.15 of Lenstra's [*Galois theory for schemes*](https://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf)

Comment: The key point is that given a group $G$, acting on a set $S$ simply transitively, the automorphisms of $S$ that commute with the action of $G$ are themselves isomorphic to $G$.  Here $G$ is the group of deck transformations, which acts simply  transitively on $Y_{\overline{x}}$, and which the automorphisms of the fiber functor must commute with, showing that the automorphisms of the fiber functor map to the group of deck transformations. That's all that's going on.